# How to input an image and a mask simultaneously in caffe?

Tags: caffe

What is the most elegant way to preprocess my input data using a mask in caffe?
Currently my input is simply an image which is transformed according to the prototxt file. Can someone provide a code snippet how to modify the prototxt file such that it is taking two inputs (image and mask) and multiplies them together?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageSegData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  top: "data_dim"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 321
    mean_value: 104
    mean_value: 116
    mean_value: 122
  }
  image_data_param {
    root_folder: "/home/myUsername/datasets/myDataset"
    source: "myDataset/list/trainFiles.txt"
    batch_size: 10
    shuffle: true
    label_type: PIXEL
  }
}

layer {
  name: "mask"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "mask"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  image_data_param {
    root_folder: "/home/myUsername/datasets/myDataset"
    source: "myDataset/list/trainMaskFiles.txt"
    batch_size: 10
    shuffle: true
    label_type: PIXEL
  }
}


########## Product ############
layer {
  name: "product"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "mask"
  top: "product"
  eltwise_param { operation: PROD }
}
```

Problems are:

1. How can I make sure that caffe keeps the order of images and corresponding masks? Since both input layers have the option 'shuffle' I guess they might be shuffeled independently.
2. The same problem holds for the option "crop_size: 321" which I would also need to be performed at the same spot for every image and it's mask
3. My original images have a size of 513 x 513. Unfortunately caffe crashes with a segmentation fault when I increase the crop size for images and mask ~160 pixels. since below 160 pixels everything is working, I don't think that there is a problem in the prototxt files. However also from memory perspective this shouldn't happen. I have a 12 GB Titan GPU and the model without mask is around 3GB on the memory. So I don't think that simply adding a mask is increasing the memory by much.
4. Right now I'm storing the masks as 3 channel png files, which restricts me to integer values between 0 and 255.

Comment: Are you using the original distribution of caffe or a modified version (e.g. deeplab)? I am asking because, as of now, the original distribution does not have an "ImageSegData" layer.

Comment: I'm using the deeplab version, but the question should remain the same for caffe and "ImageData" instead of "ImageSegData"

Answer (score 1):

Where, I am not sure yet, but I think you can take a try by modifying the source code of caffe where it implements **ReadImageToCVMat** function. In this function, it calls an opencv function **cv::imread**, let the second parameter be **-1** instead of other flags. After you modify it and rebuild caffe, opencv should read a 'png' file with its alpha channel where you put your mask. I think this should work. Just try it.